# What is the use of イ. in this document?

Tags: words

While reading this [page](https://www.boj.or.jp/announcements/release_2020/rel200909a.pdf), which is about the Bank of Japan, I came across イ.

日本銀行は、日本銀行当座預金のうち、ゼロ金利が適用されるマクロ加算残高 の算出に用いる基準比率(「補完当座預金制度基本要領」4.(3)**イ.**に定める 基準比率)について、次のとおり定めることとしました。

I am not sure about the meaning of it. Is it interest?

Answer (score 6):

「イ」is part of the numbering format for legal documents and is used to for subsections.

The order is [いろは順](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AF%E9%A0%86), and would go: イ、ロ、ハ、ニ、ホ、ヘ、ト... In English this would be "a, b, c..." or maybe "i, ii, iii..."

If you read the announcements correctly, is says:

> ...the benchmark ratio (as determined under 2.3.イ in "Principal Terms
> and Conditions of Complementary Deposit Facility" has been determined
> as follows.

So you would need to look up the specified article (2.3.イ) in the specified document ["補完当座預金制度基本要領"](https://www.boj.or.jp/mopo/measures/term_cond/yoryo37.htm/). (There is an [English version](https://www.boj.or.jp/en/mopo/measures/term_cond/yoryo36.htm/) of the document, and there it is listed as 2.3.a.

If you want to read up on the basic formatting of legal documents, Wikipedia has an [article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E4%BB%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F). This [pdf](http://www.hpsca.hokkaido-c.ed.jp/63kenkyuutaikai/oshima/23.pdf) also makes it easy to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use katakana as bullet points like this when subdividing documents. If you look at the text of the [specific document in question](https://www.boj.or.jp/mopo/measures/term_cond/yoryo37.htm/), you'll see it has a section 4:

```
4．適用利率
```

It has a subsection 3:

```
（3）付利対象積み期間...
```

And that has a subsection `イ`:

```
イ．基準平均残高に別に定める一定比率（以下「基準比率」という。）を乗じた金額
```

I think it's also very common to use `㋐`, `㋑` etc. For example from [here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B):

```
❸ 他にある作用を与える。他に影響を及ぼす。
  ① 好ましくないことを相手に及ぼす。 「妻にはずいぶん苦労を－・けてきた」 「他人に迷惑を－・ける」
  ②
    ㋐ 人に対してある感情を持つ。「先輩に思いを－・ける」「犯人に情けを－・ける」「 …に疑いを－・ける」
```